# Accessing username and password through OAuth

Tags: oauth, passwords, auth0, password-encryption

I am trying to access the usernames and passwords of people entering my site, using the access token. However I am getting an authorization code not an access token. Is it also possible to have access to the username and password of people logged into my site that they use for other sites, so that my site can act as a plaintext password manager where they can see their passwords for all sites. But the OAuth token returns an encoded string instead of an actual username or password in plaintext, so I cannot see the passwords myself nor show them to the users. Please can I have some method to access the password without encryption?

I tried to use Auth0 as well but this did not work because of the same problem. None of the resources I tried were able to store and give plaintext passwords.

Comment: Thats not how oauth works your not going to ever see someones password.

Comment: So I can't use oauth if I need this functionality? That is unfortunate. I also wanted to prevent users from selecting common passwords such as 123456, but this will not be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passwords are (**and should**) one-way-encrypted, so even if someone successfully accesses their stored values, they will still be useless.

In the following thought process RP will be raw password, that is, some text that the user enters when logging in in order to authenticate and EP will be the encrypted password, that is, the result of encrypting the password.

It's important to be aware of this congruency:

> encryption(RP) === EP

So, when a password is being stored, encryption(RP) is being called and the resulting EP is being stored into the place where it is to be located, usually into a database.

When a user is logging in, he types in RP and the backend will call encryption(RP) and compare with the EP of the user to be authenticated. If encryption(RP) does not match the stored EP, then the user entered an incorrect password. Otherwise he entered a correct password.

Now, you want to check the passwords of the users. The best way to do this is to have an authentication that does not allow users to register with weak passwords.

Yet, if you want to detect which already stored passwords are weak, then you can do the following:

- create or generate a list of all the weak passwords you can imagine
- loop this list

  - call encryption(listitem)
  - store the result somewhere
- once this is ready, search for EP values in your database that match the result of the encryption of weak passwords and notify your users that they should change their password.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem with the weak passwords. I have realised that accessing passwords of other websites is a security breach as well, so this can't be done.